# Android ViewModel keeps initialising ArrayList

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist, viewmodel

For the last two days I've been trying to use a ViewModel to store an ArrayList. However, every time I access the ViewModel it initialises the ArrayList, removing the data stored inside it.

I've tried including methods in the ViewModel to control initialisation of the ArrayList, but it hasn't helped. Every time the ViewModel is accessed it resets the ArrayList to 'null.'

Why is this happening and how can I stop it?

**ViewModel_Quiz.java**

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ViewModel_Quiz extends ViewModel {

    ArrayList<String> checkboxStatus;

    public void sendCheckboxStatus(ArrayList<String> arrayList){
        checkboxStatus = arrayList;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getCheckboxStatus(){
        return checkboxStatus;
    }
}
```

**FragmentQuiz_Selection.java**

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.support.constraint.Group;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class FragmentQuiz_Selection extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

private FloatingActionButton fab_start;
//Create member variable for Checkbox loops
private boolean mChecked;
//Create ArrayList for QuizSelection
private ArrayList<String> mQuizSelection = new ArrayList<>();
//Create boolean for Expand/Collapse
//boolean iv_group_instruments = false;
//Create View variable
private View mView;
//Variables for database
private SQLiteDatabase mInstrumentsDB;
private InstrumentsDbHelper instrumentsDb;
//This contains the same data as mQuizSelection. It's used to prepare the database and populate mTotalRows.
private String[] mQuizSelectionArray;
//This is used as part of quizPrep() to populate mTotalRows. This may note need to be a memberVariable.
private int mTotalRows;
//This contains the total number of columns for the user's selection.
private int mTotalColumns;
//This holds all of the column/row pairs for the quiz.
private ArrayList<String> mQuizList = new ArrayList<>();
//This variable is used to interface with MainActivity
private OnQuizStarted mCallback;
//This ArrayList holds the CheckBox status for restoring the user's state
private ArrayList<String> mCheckboxStatus = new ArrayList<>();

public static FragmentQuiz_Selection newInstance() {
    FragmentQuiz_Selection fragment = new FragmentQuiz_Selection();
    return fragment;
}

//Create an interface to communicate with MainActivity
public interface OnQuizStarted {
    void onQuizStarted (ArrayList<String> arrayList);
}
// Connect the interface to MainActivity

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallback = (OnQuizStarted) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnQuizStarted");
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //Store views in variable
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_quiz_selection, container, false);

    // Set onClickListeners
    setOnClickListeners();

    //Ensure all Checkboxes are set to 'false'
    ViewGroup constraintLayout = (ViewGroup) mView.findViewById(R.id.quiz_menu_layout);
    loopCheckboxesFalse(constraintLayout);

    //Create onClickListener for 'start' FAButton
    fab_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        //If you click the FAButton, start the Quiz
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Create variable for ConstraintLayout
            ViewGroup constraintLayout = (ViewGroup) mView.findViewById(R.id.quiz_menu_layout);
            quizStart(constraintLayout);
        }
    });

    return mView;
}

//Handle actions when the user is returning to the Fragment
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i("LIFECYCLE CHANGE", "Quiz_Selection, onResume has been called!");
    //Get mCheckboxStatus from ViewModel
    ViewModel_Quiz viewmodel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ViewModel_Quiz.class);
    if (viewmodel.getCheckboxStatus() != null && !(viewmodel.getCheckboxStatus().isEmpty())) {
        mCheckboxStatus = viewmodel.getCheckboxStatus();
        setCheckboxStatus(mCheckboxStatus);
    }
    //If mChecked is 'true,' show FAButton. If mChecked is 'false,' hide FAButton.
    ViewGroup layout = mView.findViewById(R.id.quiz_menu_layout);
    mChecked = loopCheckboxesBoolean(layout);
    fabButton(mChecked, fab_start);
}

//Handle actions when the user is leaving, but not necessarily destroying, the Fragment
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.i("LIFECYCLE CHANGE", "Quiz_Selection, onPause has been called!");
    mCheckboxStatus.clear();
    recordCheckboxStatus(mCheckboxStatus);
    //Send mCheckboxStatus to ViewModel
    ViewModel_Quiz viewmodel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ViewModel_Quiz.class);
    viewmodel.sendCheckboxStatus(mCheckboxStatus);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view instanceof CheckBox) {
        onCheckboxClicked(view);
    } else if (view instanceof ImageView) {
        onExpandCollapse(view);
    }
}

//METHOD:   Set Checkbox status for 'onCreate'
private void setCheckboxStatus (ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
    ViewGroup layout = mView.findViewById(R.id.quiz_menu_layout);
    int childCount = layout.getChildCount();
    //Iterate through the layout's CheckBox views
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View view = layout.getChildAt(i);
        //If item is a Checkbox, assign it as true or false
        if (view instanceof CheckBox) {
            if (arrayList.get(0) == "y") {
                ((CheckBox) view).setChecked(true);
                arrayList.remove(0);
            } else if (arrayList.get(0) == "n") {
                ((CheckBox) view).setChecked(false);
                arrayList.remove(0);
            }
        }
    }
}

//METHOD:   Store Checkbox status for 'onPause'
private void recordCheckboxStatus (ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
    ViewGroup layout = mView.findViewById(R.id.quiz_menu_layout);
    int childCount = layout.getChildCount();
    //Iterate through the layout's views
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View view = layout.getChildAt(i);
        //If item is a Checkbox && Checkbox is 'checked,' add 'y' to the arrayList.
        if (view instanceof CheckBox && ((CheckBox) view).isChecked()) {
            arrayList.add("y");
        //Else if item is a Checkbox && Checkbox is 'not checked,' add 'n' to the arrayList.
        } else if (view instanceof CheckBox && !((CheckBox) view).isChecked()){
            arrayList.add("n");
        //Else if item is not a Checkbox, skip this view and move to the next one
        } else {}
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Not a direct answer to your specific question but I would recommend using `LiveData` when using `ViewModel` like this.  Following has more info on that including use it in ViewModel - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why I should be using LiveData when using ViewModel this way?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use MutableLiveData in yout ViewModel.

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ViewModel_Quiz extends ViewModel {

    MutableLiveData<Arraylist<String>> checkboxStatus;

    public void sendCheckboxStatus(ArrayList<String> arrayList){
        checkboxStatus.postValue(arrayList);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getCheckboxStatus(){
        return checkboxStatus;
    }
}
```